# angular jasmine, trying to test a factory function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

i am really new to angular and attempting to unittest for the first time.
i have the following module:

```
var app = angular.
module('webportal',
[
    'vr.directives.slider',
    'angular-flexslider',
    'LocalStorageModule',
    'multi-select',
    'djds4rce.angular-socialshare'
]).run(function ($FB) {//facebook share...should we move this somewhere else?
    $FB.init('xxxxx')
});
```

and the following two factories:

```
angular.module('webportal').factory('uri', function () {

    var uri = {};

    uri.base = '';

    uri.setBase = function (base) {
        uri.base = base;
    };


    uri.getBase = function () {
        return uri.base;
    }

    return uri;
});

app.factory('portal', ['uri', function (uri) {
    var portal = {};
    portal.getLink = function (id) {
        return uri.getBase() + langHalf + '/property/' + id;
    };
    return portal;
}])
```

I am trying to unittest the functions inside the uri and portal factory.

Here is my attempt:

```
describe('Unit: Factory Test', function () {

    var uri;

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.module('vr.directives.slider', []);
        angular.mock.module('angular-flexslider', []);
        angular.mock.module('LocalStorageModule', []);
        angular.mock.module('multi-select', []);
        angular.mock.module('djds4rce.angular-socialshare', []);

        module('webportal', [
            'vr.directives.slider',
            'angular-flexslider',
            'LocalStorageModule',
            'multi-select',
            'djds4rce.angular-socialshare'
        ]);

        beforeEach(module('uri'));


    });


    it("baseSettingTest", function () {
        var uri = new uri();
        //var uri = new uri;
        var baseSettingTest = 'testing base';
        uri.setBase(baseSettingTest);

        expect(uri.getBase()).toEqual(baseSettingTest);

    })

})
```

So when i run this , it fails with the following error:

```
FAILED Unit: Factory Test baseSettingTest
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/base/tests/portaltestjs/portal.test.js:50:19)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1759:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1747:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1733:10)
    at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:569:35)
    at Spec.execute (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:318:10)
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2072:43)
    at attemptAsync (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1789:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1745:16)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1733:10)
  window.__karma__.result   
  specDone  
  dispatch  
  (anonymous function)  
  specResultCallback    
  complete  
  clearStack    
  QueueRunner.run   
  QueueRunner.execute   
  Env.queueRunnerFactory    
  Spec.execute  
  fn    
  attemptAsync  
  QueueRunner.run   
  QueueRunner.execute   
  Env.queueRunnerFactory    
  Suite.execute 
  fn    
  attemptAsync  
  QueueRunner.run   
  QueueRunner.execute   
  Env.queueRunnerFactory    
  Suite.execute 
  allFns.push.fn    
  attemptAsync  
  QueueRunner.run   
  QueueRunner.execute   
  Env.queueRunnerFactory    
  Env.execute   
  env.executeFiltered   
  (anonymous function)  
  window.__karma__.loaded   
  (anonymous function)  
Skipped 0 tests
```

So clearly i am not intializing uri properly.

1. How do i initialize uri factory? and try to test a function ?
2. How do i intialize portal factory?and try to test a function ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the service and then you can call methods on that service, here's how I did it in my [ng-boilerplate](https://github.com/ianwalter/ng-boilerplate) project:

```
  beforeEach(module('ng-boilerplate'));

  var NameService;
  beforeEach(inject(function (_NameService_) {
    NameService = _NameService_;
  }));

  describe('#formatName()', function() {
    it('should title case a given string', function() {
      expect(NameService.formatName('IAN')).to.equal('Ian');
  // ...etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you must add refference to your 'uri' template

```
describe('Unit: Factory Test', function () {

    var uri;

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.module('vr.directives.slider', []);
        angular.mock.module('angular-flexslider', []);
        angular.mock.module('LocalStorageModule', []);
        angular.mock.module('multi-select', []);
        angular.mock.module('djds4rce.angular-socialshare', []);

        module('webportal', [
            'vr.directives.slider',
            'angular-flexslider',
            'LocalStorageModule',
            'multi-select',
            'djds4rce.angular-socialshare'
        ]);

        //beforeEach(module('uri')); please comment out this line
        beforeEach(module('webportal')) //you should load module instead of load your factory

    });

    // Use below block code to inject your factory into uri variable
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$injector_) {
        uri = _$injector_.get('uri');   //Inject uri factory into uri variable
    }));

    // For now your uri factory available for testing

    it("baseSettingTest", function () {
        spyOn(uri, 'setBase'); //spy on you setBase function

        var baseSettingTest = 'testing base';
        uri.setBase(baseSettingTest);       

        expect(uri.getBase).toHaveBeenCalled(); //Make sure getBase function was called
    })
})
```

I have modified something in your code, help it can help you